# Algorithm - Aggregate duplicate records

Tags: c#, algorithm

I would like to know if there is a well-known and efficient algorithm that find duplicates in a List, sum them all on one of them and remove the other ?

For example, `1 1 3 2 1 2 3` becomes `3 4 6`.

Comment: You can do this easily in LINQ

Comment: Can you give me any hint ? I'm not confortable with linq expressions.

Comment: `var results = list.GroupBy(x => x).Select(g => g.Sum());`?

Comment: Histogram of values would work well.  O(n) complexity

Comment: @juharr Trying to understand what x ang g are in your expression and how can i modify it for a list of class and its properties. Thank you all for the quick answers.

Comment: @YthioCsi `x => x` is lambda. Basically he takes value `x` from the list, and uses it, since it's just an integer with no properties. It could work for classes like `listOfClass.GroupBy(x => x.Surname)`. `x` is simply the name of the element you take from the list when you use lambda. Read more on it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-operator

Comment: it's called [lambda expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions) `x` stands for each element in `list` and `g` stands for each element in the resulting list after `GroupBy` has been executed

Comment: And thank you. I'll have to overload Sum() if I want to use that with a class i made, don't I ?

Comment: No. As I said, you're using integers so you can just use the element in your lambda as it is. For classes, you'd sum the property of the element: `var totalAge = people.Sum(person => person.Age);`

Comment: @ThePerplexedOne I want to test and create a class with only a int property and a constructor to initialize instances, but if i'm doing `myObjectList.GroupBy(x => x).Select(g => g.Sum(y => y.Value));` the result is a List<int> instead of a List<MyObject>, did I missunderstand something ?

Comment: @YthioCsi In that case you need `myOjectList.GroupBy(x => x.Value).Select(g => new YourClassHere{ Value = g.Sum()});`  Basically you create new items with the sums.  Note that if you did GroupBy(`x => x`) on a list of custom class objects that it will do reference comparisons for the grouping which is likely not what you'd want unless you overwrite `Equals` and `GetHashCode`.

Comment: @juharr Interesting, thank you. Just to see how far we can go, what if `myObject` is an abstract class and my list contains two concrete implementations `Object1` and `Object2` with different properties, how can i decide in the linq expression which constructor class to call in the Select ? This time it seems that linq can't solve it, isn't it ?

Comment: @YthioCsi In that case you'd have problems with the grouping.  It coudl only group on a common property that's exposed by the abstract class.  Then you could end up grouping objects of different types together in which case there isn't a good way to determine which to use.  And even if you just had one type with additional properties you'd have to decide how to aggregate their values as well.

Answer (score 2):

Using the `GroupBy()` and `Sum()` extension methods you can accomplish what you want:

```
int[] nums = new int[] { 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 7 };       
var result = nums.GroupBy(number => number).Select(grouping => grouping.Sum());
```

My solution also accounts for if there is only one instance of a value, it still keeps it in the result (obviously without summing it).

Working fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/UFbP6m).

Answer (score 1):

Just `GroupBy`:

```
 int[] source = new int[] { 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3 };

 var result = source
   .GroupBy(x => x, (k, s) => s.Sum())
   .OrderBy(x => x) // if you want result being ordered, "3 4 6" (not "3 6 4")
   .ToArray(); 

 // 3 4 6
 Console.Write(string.Join(" ", result));
```

Comment: Wouldn't `ToArray()` be unnecessary?  Especially since you're storing it in a new variable, then immediately calling `string.Join()` (which takes an `IEnumerable<T>`)

Comment: @maccettura `String.Join` works on `String[]` arrays

Comment: @adjan `string.Join()` works on `IEnumerable<T>` [as well](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421(v=vs.110).aspx), making the `ToArray()` call unnecessary.  If you check the [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/UFbP6m) I posted in my answer you will see it in action.

Comment: @maccettura Right. Sorry. +1

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
int[] numbers = new int[] { ..... };

var result = from i in numbers
             group i by i into g
             select g.Sum();
```

If you want to know which number occurs how often, you can use the following snippet:

```
var result = from i in numbers
             group i by i into g
             select new { Value = g.Key, Count = g.Sum() };
```

The results of which you can use as follows:

```
foreach (var elem in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"The number '{elem.Value}' occurs {elem.Count} times.");
}
```

---

If you do not like the LINQ query syntax, you could use the following code:

```
var result = numbers.GroupBy(i => i)
                    .Select(g => new { Value = g.Key, Count = g.Sum() });
```

*Do not forget to include a using-reference to `global::System.Linq`*

---

See the following links for further LINQ examples:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/group-query-results
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/group-clause